# Bootstrap xs class is not resizing .thumbnail images correctly when screen becomes too small

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap, was going through w3schools lessons. I was trying following example:
[W3Schools Tryit Editor](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_img_thumbnail2&stacked=h)

This example does not seem to work when I change the class from **class="col-md-4"** to **class="col-xs-4"** for all **divs**. All the images are losing their aspect ratios when I am resizing the browser to minimum width.

I think this behavior is not correct and images should resize and stack.

Please help me understand this behavior.

Comment: Try to apply both classes as follows `<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">`

Comment: Still not working but I wanted to know why it was not working in first place. I am setting the correct class as per documentation, it should work, right? Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The behaviour is because of inline styles for images in the code `<img src="pulpitrock.jpg" alt="Pulpit Rock" style="width:150px;height:150px">`. instead of inline styling add `img-responsive` to the images.

Comment: Understood. But, how come is it working fine with md classes?

Comment: twitter bootstrap does not relate to bootstrapping

Answer (score 1):

You just have to remove inline css from the 
`<img src="pulpitrock.jpg" alt="Pulpit Rock" style="width:150px;height:150px">` 
and replace it with

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="pulpitrock.jpg" alt="Pulpit Rock">
```

and if you want to add different sizes for thumbnail add one more class in your .css file, don't use inline.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the col-md or col-xs classes it has to do with that the images are wrapped in a thumbnail.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <a href="pulpitrock.jpg" class="thumbnail">
    <p>Pulpit Rock: A famous tourist attraction in Forsand, Ryfylke, Norway.</p>    
    <img src="pulpitrock.jpg" alt="Pulpit Rock" style="width:150px;height:150px">
  </a>
</div>
```

As you can see the `<a>` tag in this code above has the class of thumbnail.  If you remove this class the images will overflow the div.  In bootstraps css they have a max-width of 100% for all images in a thumbnail or thumnbnail `<a>`.  If you want them to be responsive you should give them a class and a width in percentages and don't specify height or give height of auto and not use inline styles.  If you want to remove the max-width you need to set this to have a max-width of none like this but this will cause the image to overflow the div.

```
.thumbnail > a img, .thumbnail > img{
  max-width: none;
}
```

Here is a fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/tu9xjdbk/)